# ABCD is a square of side 4cm. E is a point in the interior of the square such that CED is equilateral. Then find the area of ACE in sq.centimeters.

Tags: geometry

The given answer is $4*(\sqrt{3} - 1)$ 
I tried all the methods but could not match the answer. 
 
Please tell if the question is wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you drawn a picture? Because it seems like $CD$ is one of the edges of this equilateral triangle, and so you have an equilateral triangle with a known side length...

Comment: yes...CD is one of the sides of the equilateral triangle

Comment: @pjs36 The area needed is of ACE

Comment: The answer you mention is right.

Answer (score 1):

Area of triangle $CED$ is $4\sqrt{3}$. 
Area of triangle $AED$ is $(0.5)*ab\sin(C)$ = $(0.5)*4*4*\sin(30^o)$ = $4$ or $(0.5)*base*height $ base being $4$, height $2$. 
 
Area of triangle $ACD$ is $(0.5)*4*4 = 8$
Area of triangle $AEC = ADE + EDC - ACD$ 
$\implies 4\sqrt{3} +4 -8$ = $4(\sqrt{3} -1)$

Comment: The area of $\triangle AED$ is easy to compute. It has base $4$ and height $2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Quite true. Thank you.